# Sqoop import is showing error - Jobtracker is not yet running

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to do sqoop import. It shows error Jobtracker is not running.

But I tried with eval by selecting few rows it works. 
But while doing import I am getting error. I have included snapshot of both eval and import function which I have tried.

I tried function hadoop command (hadoop fs -ls, -put)  is working.

[image]

[image]

I started start-all.sh.
Afterwards I check with jps then all daemon run.

After few minutes, all daemon stop.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQOOP Eval function just acts on the RDBMS database and returns you the resultset. Here hadoop does not come into picture.
SQOOP Import function tries to import the data from RDBMS and load it into HDFS. The namenode is not able to connect to the HDFS. Restart hadoop and check the job tracker and namenode logs. Check whether the namenode and datanode storage directories mentioned in the the HDFS-Site.xml are available else point to a new directory.